# How to see the lost local history in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to check some past copies of my project on IntelliJ which I hadn't committed. Couple days ago, the copies was there but now some copies are gone. For example, I was still able to see the versions in November last week but today I checked it only showed versions from December.

As far as I know, local history is only lost when I update it or invalidate the function, which I never did. Is there a way to restore the local history?

Answer (score 2):

The local history stores the information for 5 working days only (5 days in which you did any work on your project). It is not intended to store the complete development history of your project since the beginning of time.

There is no way to restore local history data that has been deleted because it was too old.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I will commit my work more often in case something happens again... And the commit history will always be there, right?

Comment: Sure, the commit history is always preserved.